# Show that $P(Y> 0)\ge E[Y]^2/{E}[Y^2]$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, inequality

Let $Y$ be an integrable random variable such that $E(Y)>0$. Then 
$$P(Y> 0)\ge E[Y]^2/{E}[Y^2]$$

I am trying to figure this inequality out. My idea is to find a polynomial $p(Y)$ of second order such that $$1_{Y>0} \ge p(Y)$$ then to take the expectation in both sides giving $$P(Y> 0)\ge E[p(Y)]$$ and the polynomial must be like $E[p(Y)] = E[Y]^2/{E}[Y^2]$ or at least $E[p(Y)] \ge E[Y]^2/{E}[Y^2]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $Y$ has finite variance, by [cauchy-schwarz-inequality](/questions/tagged/cauchy-schwarz-inequality),

$$
\operatorname{E}[Y] \le \operatorname{E}[ Y \, \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y > 0 \}} ] \le \operatorname{E}[Y^2]^{1/2} \operatorname{P}( Y > 0)^{1/2}.
$$

If $E[Y^2] = \infty$, since $E[Y] < \infty$, then the inequality holds trivially.

Comment: I think you should have $E[Y] \leq E[Y \textbf{1}_{\{Y >0\}}]$.

Comment: @kccu Thank you!  Typo fixed.